# Windows: Using events for shared memory synchronization

Tags: c, windows, winapi, events, driver

I am using events to synchronize two processes who access shared memory. What I want to achieve looks like this:

Process A: Signal event for process B

Process A: Wait until process B replies

Process B: Receive event, do memory operation

Process B: Signal event for process A

Process B: Wait until process A replies

In summary I have two processes who are supposed to alternately access shared memory while making sure that they only act after they received a signal from the other process.

Here is how I create the event (it's created in the kernel and shared between a driver and a usermode program):

```
ZwCreateEvent(&hEvent, EVENT_ALL_ACCESS, &oa, SynchronizationEvent, FALSE);
```

Here is how I open the event in the usermode program:

```
HANDLE ghWriteEvent = OpenEvent(EVENT_MODIFY_STATE, FALSE, TEXT("Global\\WriteEvent01"));
```

This is how I currently signal the event in the usermode:

```
SetEvent(ghWriteEvent);
ResetEvent(ghWriteEvent);
WaitForSingleObject(ghWriteEvent, INFINITE);
```

This is how I signal the even in the kernel:

```
KeSetEvent(kEvent, LOW_REALTIME_PRIORITY, FALSE);
KeResetEvent(kEvent);
KeWaitForSingleObject(kEvent, Executive, KernelMode, TRUE, NULL);
```

I use SetEvent() so the other process is signaled and ResetEvent() afterwards so that WaitForSingleObject() only succeeds when it receives a signal from the other process.

Is this the correct way of synchronizing two processes? I am not sure since this does work 90% of the time but sometimes it doesn't.

E.g. it works when I print stuff to the console after calling WaitForSingleObject(). When I remove the print the synchronization sometimes fails. This makes me believe that there needs to be a certain delay between the synchronization calls.

Is there an obvious mistake I have overlooked? Thank you.

Comment: `SetEvent + ResetEvent ==`[`PulseEvent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-pulseevent). really you need here 2 events object *A* and *B* . one do - `write_data();set(A);wait(B)` and another `wait(A);process_data();set(B);`

Comment: SetEvent + ResetEvent != PulseEvent. PulseEvent is bad. PulseEvent is unreliable and should not be used.

Comment: For your work, it might be better to use a mutex.
This way you only need one mutex. Not two events.

Comment: Ok this makes a lot of sense. It seems like mutexes have been designed for my exact problem.

Comment: SetEvent + ResetEvent is exactly PulseEvent. *PulseEvent is bad. PulseEvent is unreliable and should not be used* - exactly because this your code SetEvent + ResetEvent is bad and unreliable

Comment: @Michael mutex can not be used for **signal** that data is ready. mutex only for exlusive access. so mutex here is ofcourse not solution at all

Comment: You can use two events, one for user->kernel to signal "ready", and the other from kernel->user to signal "finished". If you only use one then calling `SetEvent` followed by `ResetEvent` means the other side can miss the event altogether (since `SetEvent` is not guaranteed to release a waiting thread immediately).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Jonathan Potter, RbMm and Michael pointed out the usage of only one event to synchronize is unreliable since you have to use "PulseEvent".

The solution to my problem is using two events. One for signaling that the kernel mode is done and one for signaling that the user mode is done. This solved my problem.